# Script Error when trying to print a page from IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Get the following "Internet Explorer Script Error" when trying to print from IE8 on XP SP3:

```
 ! An error has occurred in the script on this page
 Line: 291
 Char: 1
 Error: The specified module could not be found
 URL: res://ieframe.dll/preview.js

 Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
                   Yes    No
```

Does anyone know why this is occuring?  And how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some evidence that registering ole32.dll can fix this issue.

Open a command prompt and type `regsvr32 ole32.dll`

If those don't work, I'm seeing that you can also register the following files to fix this issue:

```
regsvr32 oleaut32.dll
regsvr32 actxprxy.dll
```

[Source](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en/InternetExplorer/thread/5bebf9be-8e8a-4932-b071-0d5171fe4a57)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML page in the website contains a reference to a missing file, preview.js.

What you can do is :

1. get in touch with the administrator of the website
2. turn off script errors : [How to Stop Internet Explorer Script Error Messages](http://www.ehow.com/how_2033268_stop-internet-explorer.html)
3. if you are using a Print button furnished by the page in question, use instead the browser's print
4. try another browser, which might ignore these problems, for example Firefox
5. take a screenshot of the page and print that instead